# Highcharts - Get crossing point of crossing series

Tags: highcharts, regression, series, interception

I am currently trying to extract the points of multiple crossings of series (a,b,c,d) of a specific series (x). I can't seem to find any function that can aid me in this task.

My best bet is to measure the distance of every single point in x with every single point in a,b,c,d... and assume when the distance reaches under some threshold, the point must be a crossing point. I think this approach is far too computational heavy and seems "dirty". I believe there must be easier or better ways, even perhaps functions within highcharts own API.

I have searched various sources and sites, but I can't really find any solutions to this. A few people have used regression as a part of their solution. I don't know much about regression, but perhaps regression is the only way?

Also due to the "complex" nature of our series, I also believe regression is rather difficult to utilize.

Comment: You want to find the intersection of line segments?  For instance, in this simplistic example, http://jsfiddle.net/94gfv/, you'd return `(0.5, 2)`?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is the intersections I am looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a well studied [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm).  Before optimizing, though, I'd try the "computational heavy" brute-force approach.  Borrowing from the [excellent answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect), I've coded up a quick integration with highcharts (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/ywLyU/1/)):

```
get_line_intersection = function(p0,p1,p2,p3)
{        
    var p0_x = p0.x;
    var p0_y = p0.y;
    var p1_x = p1.x;
    var p1_y = p1.y;
    var p2_x = p2.x;
    var p2_y = p2.y;
    var p3_x = p3.x;
    var p3_y = p3.y;  

    var s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
    s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;     s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
    s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;     s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;

    var s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
    var t = ( s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

    if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1)
    {
        return [p0_x + (t * s1_x),p0_y + (t * s1_y)];
    }

    return false;
}

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            name: 'line1',
            data: $.map(new Array(10), function(){return Math.random() * 10;})
        }, {
            name: 'line2',
            data: $.map(new Array(10), function(){return Math.random() * 10;})
        }, {
            name: 'intersect',
            data: [],
            type: 'scatter'
            }
        ]
    }, function(chart){
        var s0 = chart.series[0].points;
        var s1 = chart.series[1].points;
        var s2 = chart.series[2];
        var n0 = s0.length;
        var n1 = s1.length;
        var i,j,isect;
        for (i = 1; i < n0; i++){
           for (j = 1; j < n1; j++){
               if (isect = get_line_intersection(s0[i-1],s0[i],
                                   s1[j-1],s1[j])){
                   s2.addPoint(isect, false, false);

               }
           } 
        }
        chart.redraw();
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up not doing the implementation myself, but got someone else to do it. From the looks of his code it actually seems like he used this method. It would be neat if highcharts supported intersections more such as, mouse over intersections, interaction tooltip etc. Thanks for the answer though.