# Highchart : Add a marker where lines intersect

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I want to show some red markers where the lines intersect.Is it possible?
Or can a line be drawn where the lines intersect.

Comment: It would help if you post your chart code, or a jsfiddle. The short answer is that it is possible, but may need some effort on your part to identify the cross-over points.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426603/highcharts-get-crossing-point-of-crossing-series