# How to change color of line above or below specify curve line in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to change color of line for specified range in Highcharts? I have enclosed an image which presents expected result.
[image: Expected result - example]

I know that I can use the separated series, but it's uncomfortable. Maybe there is some wrapper (plugin) which makes this process easier.

Comment: Make the second color it's own array. and remove those values from the initial array. So you'll create gaps in the first array that are filled by the second in a different color.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that I can create separated series, but it's a little bit inconvenient, because I'll have to determine an intersection point and create proper arrays by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I far as I know, there isn't any wrapper for that. I would to this in two steps:

- calculate [intersection points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426603/highcharts-get-crossing-point-of-crossing-series)
- use two separate series **or** [multicolor-series](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series) plugin (multiple colors within one line).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a demo of something similar to your image that may be what you are looking for (and a lot of other good examples with JS.Fiddles and code) I found [this one here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/areaspline) which uses this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average fruit consumption during one week'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 150,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday',
                'Thursday',
                'Friday',
                'Saturday',
                'Sunday'
            ],
            plotBands: [{ // visualize the weekend
                from: 4.5,
                to: 6.5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)'
            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit units'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' units'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4]
        }]
    });
});
```

and has a [JS.Fiddle for it here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/areaspline/). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to change a color of line within the scope of one series. Using a "plotBands" is not what I'm looking for.