# Highcharts - Get x Value From Y value

Tags: highcharts

How can i get the x value by providing an y value between two points (**an y value which is not in the data**).
I have looked for an answer but i can only loop over the points which are present in the data: http://jsfiddle.net/royzcfed/

```
$('#button').click(function(){
y1=$('#input').val();
var points = $('#container').highcharts().series[0].points;
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if (points[i].y == y1){
    xValue = points[i].x;
    alert(xValue);
    break;   
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much larger question than you might be thinking.

It is certainly beyond the scope of Highcharts, and relates more to math in general. (ie Highcharts doesn't plot out each pixel, it tells the browser to draw a line between two points)

Some things to consider:

1) given that we don't seem to be talking about a specific distribution function, you would have to specify the two points between which you are trying to find your value. Otherwise, that y value could potentially fall anywhere on the chart and there is no way to correlate it to a specific x value.

2) the line between those two points would have to be a straight line, or one that follows a specific formulaic curve

3) if it is not a straight line, you will need to have the calculations that built the curve, and use them to locate your y and it's x.  If it is a straight line you need to calculate slope and intercept given the two points you are working with, and work from there (look into calculating linear regression)

Comment: is it possible to get coordinates of where it intersects with the series ?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426603/highcharts-get-crossing-point-of-crossing-series) should be helpful.