# Chart.js add tooltip at intersection of axes (break even)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I have a simple Chart.js line chart, which shows the costs of two decisions. I now want to show the break even of one over the other, which is basically the intersection.

I made an example of what I have so far [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o3cyhxrn/2/)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
var options = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["1", "2", "4", "6", "7", "10"],
        datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80]
            },
            {
                backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [8.84, 17.68, 35.36, 53.04, 70.72, 88.4]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top'
        }            
    }
};
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

How can I

1. Show a tooltip at the interception of the two lines
2. Show the values for the interception (inside a tooltip or at the axis)
3. Move the legend inside the chart

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersection point in line graph in Chart.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621329/intersection-point-in-line-graph-in-chart-js)

Comment: Nice that helped, even I thought it may be easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **very specific** to the problem

```
 Chart.plugins.register({
afterInit: function(chart) {
var intersect = getIntersection();
 var datasets = chart.data.datasets;
 var labels = chart.data.labels;
 labels.push(intersect.x)
    labels.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
y = labels.indexOf(intersect.x);
chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(ds,i){ds.data.splice(y, 0, intersect.y)});

 }
 })
 function getIntersection(){
  var y2=17.68, y1=8.84,x2=2,x1=1,x3 = x1, x4 = x2,
      y4=80,y3=80;
  var x=((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(x3-x4)-(x1-x2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4));
var y=((x1*y2-y1*x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3*y4-y3*x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4));
    x = Math.round(x*100)/100;
y = Math.round(y*100)/100;
return {x:x,y:y}  ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o3cyhxrn/4/

Comment: Thanks not exactly what I wanted as my values are dynamic but thank you for the idea.

Comment: you can pass the values of x1,x2,y1,y2,y3,y4, to the function from your dyanamic list