# Is it still not possible to show an intersection point between two lines in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Consider i have the followin two datasets:

```
      fillData () {
    this.datacollection = {
      labels: this.generateLabels(this.getKonto),
      datasets: [          
        {
          label: 'Loan',
          data: this.generateLabels(this.loanTotal),
          borderColor: "#ff8148",
          fill: false
        }, {
          label: 'Cost',
          data: this.generateLabels(this.costTotal).reverse(),
          borderColor: "#ffe59f",
          fill: false
        }
      ]
    },
```

Both "data"  represent an array of 10 values each. Both lines are linear. Is it possible to highlight an intersection point whereever one line crosses the other?

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004777/11989020)?

Comment: @HeadhunterKev yes, but do you know how to refactor this code for vue-chart.js? I tried this solution before, but i cant figure it out...

Comment: No, I haven't worked with Vue yet.